# Unrecognized feature gate SupportPodPidsLimit. KOPS, Kubernetes 1.23.0

Tags: kubernetes, kops

I'm spawning a kube cluster with KOPS. All works fine until I added feature gate SupportPodPidsLimit to kubelet:

`kubelet:`
   `featureGates:`
      `SupportPodPidsLimit: "true"`

Master node syslog shows:
*Failed to set feature gates from initial flags-based config" err="unrecognized feature gate: SupportPodPidsLimit*

I haven't found in KOPS or Kube docs what and why feature gates can be unknown. Kube docs say SupportPodPidsLimit exists since 1.20.0 in GA.
I'm using 1.23.0

Expecting to set *podPidsLimit*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [the list of feature gates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/)
When the gate is GA, it is enabled by default and removed. Since you are using 1.23, the feature gate does indeed no longer exist.